# How to get an additional toolbar at bottom of UISplitViewControllers root controller?

Tags: cocoa-touch, xamarin.ios

When using the standard UISplitViewController setup, there's a toolbar/navigation bar at the top of the left panel.
I would like to add an additional toolbar at the bottom and tableview in the middle, which is managed by the navigation controller.
Can anybody point my to an example?

Info: I'm using IB.

Thanks.

René

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "easy" way to accomplish this is to create a parent ViewController, housing a subview (your current UISplitViewController), and at the bottom of that VC place your toolbar.

If the events need to be passed from the toolbar to the VC, this would best be accomplished using Events and wiring the two together in the newly created parent ViewController.

Optionally, you could create a toolbar in code and add it to the detail view (or even the parent UISplitViewController as an overlay) with the .Add or .AddSubView - just be sure to set the proper frame. This might potentially overlay real estate on the detail view, so you'd want to adjust the frame there as well so that you can access all of the view.

Comment: The basic idea is correct. I did not want the toolbar at the very bottom of the screen under the split controller, but under the navigation controller. But the solutiuon really is: Create view, house a subview and a toolbar in it. Then add the navigation controller's view to the subview.

Comment: Apple specifically states the a UISplitViewController must be the root view controller for the window. Making the split view a subview of another view controller is likely to cause problems.